# How do you force a figure to span multiple monitors in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I'm using MATLAB R2011a on a multi-monitor Linux system (Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.4). The answer to this may be dependent on what operating system or graphics subsystem you are using.

Run the following code on a multi-monitor system:

```
mons = get(0,'MonitorPositions') ;
first_monitor_width = mons(1,3) ; % width of first monitor in pixels
fig = figure ; % create a new figure window
x_pos = 0 ;
y_pos = 100 ;
x_dim = first_monitor_width + 300 ; % Set fig to be 300 pxwider than left monitor
y_dim = 500 ;
set(fig,'OuterPosition',[x_pos y_pos x_dim y_dim]) ; % Or use 'Position'; same.
```

We asked the figure to have its left edge at the left side of the left monitor, and to have a width equal to the width of the left monitor, plus 300 pixels. Thus the figure should span across both monitors.

But instead, MATLAB creates the figure with a width equal to the width of the left monitor (on my computer, that's 1920 pixels).

Now, a twist:

Manually (with your mouse), drag the bottom-right corner of the figure so that it spans both monitors (i.e. so that the figure's width is greater than the width of one monitor). Now run the following line of code again:

```
set(fig,'OuterPosition',[x_pos y_pos x_dim y_dim]) ;
```

Now it works! In other words, once you have forced the figure to "break the barrier" between monitors, MATLAB treats the entire contiguous display space as a single canvas.

Note that if you use your mouse to resize the window so that it's once again entirely within one monitor, and then run the `set(fig,'OuterPosition', ...)` call again, it will return to the original behaviour, where the figure is only allowed to be resized within that single window.

My question is, how do I force the figure to span multiple monitors, entirely in scripting? Like, is there a property of the figure that is something like `SpansMonitors = true` or `false` that I can set using a `set()` call?

Comment: Hmm, your first block of code works properly for me. I'm still using R2012a. Which version are you using?

Comment: I'm using R2011a on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.4 with GNOME 2.28.2. What about you? Maybe it's something that's fixed in R2012a, or (more likely) the behaviour is different on different operating systems?

Comment: I'm running Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/positioning-figures.html:

> Figure Position and Window Managers Your computer's window manager
>   controls the layout of windows on monitors and on virtual desktops. It
>   might not honor a request to place a figure window that would cause
>   the entire figure or its top border to be located off-screen. A window
>   manager also might force windows to have a certain minimum or maximum
>   width or height. Such actions can cause a figure's position to differ
>   from what you specify, and results can vary across platforms and
>   window managers.

It's probably something to do with the Metacity window manager.